# Inconsistent spatial comparison operations (ArcMap)

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

I'm trying to find geometries who's boundaries are coincident to a line. I've mostly been able to achieve this with IRelationalOperator.Touches in my code. Ideally my relation description of "FF*T*****" would work. My question comes from me playing around with the relation description.

ESRI defines Touches as:

> Two geometries are said to touch when the intersection of the
>   geometries is non-empty, but the intersection of their interiors is
>   empty.

Touch also has the spatial relation code "FF*FT****"

From that description I would expect the relation description of "F********" to return at minimum what Touches returns. However it does not.

In the following image I am comparing a green polygon and a blue polygon to a polyline. Touches will return both the green and blue polygons, but "F********" only returns the blue polygon. Why does the Touches function think there is no relationship between the interiors of the green polygon and the red line, but my custom relation description thinks there is?

[image]

Comment: Coincidence operators are hard to implement, even though it looks like the green triangle is on the line at this scale it quite likely misses slightly on the line... I usually buffer the line by a very small amount, find the polygons that intersect and then use ITopologicalOperator boundary then intersection to decide how much follows the line on a geometry by geometry basis. What are you trying to do with the geometries that follow the line?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I'm fixing some issues with geometries. When the shape has a coincident edge (along with a couple other conditions) then the fix will be applied manually. For this I only need to know if the shape is coincident. I've already located the geometries via buffer, so then I need to determine if they are coincident.

Comment: In this case I would (and have) intersect the buffer of the search line with the boundary of the polygon then find the length of the intersecting edge (esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry1Dimension)... if the search line passes through the length will be small, if it nearly follows the line the length will be greater... what values you expect for length depends on your projection and polygon perimeter.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson That's very helpful, I've been trying to figure a good way to do that.

Comment: My original question, though, still stands in that the Touch relation seems inconsistent with custom relations. I would still expect the set of features returned by the relation "F********" to contain all features returned by Touch.

Comment: I've just tried the method for finding coincident lines a couple times and noticed when the line isn't coincident I simply get back an empty geometry (since a point would be 0D). So for my purposes I don't need to check the length of the line returned, just if a non-empty geometry was returned.